# PgfPlot: Axis Arrows vs Vector Arrows

Tags: pgfplots, arrows

I've notice that the arrowheads on the axis are different than the arrowheads drawn when drawing vectors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            domain=0:1, range=0:1,
            axis lines=none,
          ]   
          \addplot [->] plot coordinates {(0,0) (0,1)}; %% make longer later axis
          \addplot [->] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)}; %% make longer later axis
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            domain=0:1, range=0:1,
            axis lines =left,
            ticks=none,
          ]          
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How do I make all the arrows look like the axis arrows? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `[->]` you should use `[-stealth]`. See the PGF/TikZ manual for different arrowheads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the arrows globally in the preamble using

```
\tikzset{>=stealth}
```

Enjoy the beautifully easy customization of [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) :)